# How can I set the job timeout using the Jenkins DSL

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-job-dsl

How can I use [the Jenkins DSL](https://github.com/jenkinsci/job-dsl-plugin/wiki/Job-reference) to set the job timeout to 10 minutes ?

From http://job-dsl.herokuapp.com/, I can enter

```
job {
  name 'ci'
  description 'Build and test the app.'
  wrappers {    
     timeout()
   }
}
```

and it generates the following block for the timeout, with a default of 3 minutes.

```
<buildWrappers>
    <hudson.plugins.build__timeout.BuildTimeoutWrapper>
        <strategy class='hudson.plugins.build_timeout.impl.AbsoluteTimeOutStrategy'>
            <timeoutMinutes>3</timeoutMinutes>
        </strategy>
        <operationList></operationList>
    </hudson.plugins.build__timeout.BuildTimeoutWrapper>
</buildWrappers>
```

What do I need to enter as the 'timeoutClosure' to get the DSL to generate

```
<timeoutMinutes>10</timeoutMinutes>
```

instead ?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The [Job DSL reference](https://jenkinsci.github.io/job-dsl-plugin/#method/javaposse.jobdsl.dsl.helpers.wrapper.WrapperContext.timeout) says that `timeout` takes a closure with `absolute()` for this case:

```groovy
job {
  wrappers {
    timeout {
      absolute(minutes = 10)
    }
  }
}
```

You can omit the `minutes =` prefix, but I find it's better to leave it explicit as to what the unit of time is.

Comment: Worth noting that `wrappers` (and thus `timeout`) is not supported for dslFactory `pipelineJob`/`multibranchPipelineJob` - the docs don't say this explicitly but it is only listed under `job`/`freeStyleJob` https://jenkinsci.github.io/job-dsl-plugin/#method/javaposse.jobdsl.dsl.jobs.FreeStyleJob.wrappers; see also https://github.com/jenkinsci/job-dsl-plugin/blob/e6d655dd5b2874f56af8bf4b99a4d622b752bb98/docs/Migration.md?plain=1#L136-L167